# Suppose that $\int_a^b{f} \le \int_a^b{g}$. Is it true that f(x)$\le$g(x)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that $\int_a^b{f(x) dx} \le \int_a^b{g(x)dx}$ . Is it true that $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$? Explain.
Is it true that there exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)\le g(c)$?

Comment: What is the $x$ in $f(x) \le g(x)$?  You need a quantifier.

Comment: @user66345: It appears that the quantifier got attached to the wrong thing: I’d just about bet that ‘for all $x\in[a,b]$’ belongs with $f(x)\le g(x)$, since it makes no sense where it is.

Answer (score 2):

HINT for the first question: Take $g$ to be the function that is identically $0$; surely you can find a nice function $f$ such that $f(a)>0$ but $\int_a^bf\le 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$0=\int\limits_0^1 0\,dx\le\int\limits_0^1\left(-\frac{4}{3}x+1\right)dx=\frac{1}{3}$$

But it *isn't* true that

$$0\le -\frac{4}{3}x+1\;\;\forall\,x\in[0,1]$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the first part has been answered, for the second part:

Suppose not, then for all $x \in [a,b], f(x) > g(x)$.  What does this say about the integrals?